# Only one monitor working Ubuntu 20.4 Nvidia

Tags: nvidia

I have a Nvidia RTX 2080ti

This is my first day using linux. Everything was working wonderfully, then I restarted and now only one monitor is working

I have no idea what I'm doing

I've gone through a few communities reading their solutions and didn't find anything similar to what I'm experiencing

I've tried to delete nvidia's drivers and reinstall, I can't find the drivers

When I try to install new drivers, it gives me an error saying I should just restart my computer. I've restarted and no success

Can anyone please help me?

Comment: Proprietary drivers like Nvidia's do not work unsigned with Secure Boot. Either use the mokutil for that purpose or, much simpler, disable Secure Boot in UEFI.